# Using Google Cloud SQL (Postgres) tables created with hibernate inaccessible

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

If you use Hibernate to create tables, those tables are inaccessible to other users (they are owned by cloudsqladmin). All attempts to GRANT permission to other users have failed, so when I'm accessing it via shell or GUI using the only credentials I have (the non-cloudsqladmin users), they have no access to these tables other than to list the columns in the table.

Through IAM I have granted the service account access to all permissions.

eg. logged in as the postgres user:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO postgres;

ERROR: permission denied for relation mytable

GRANT SELECT ON post to postgres;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation mytable

ALTER TABLE public.mytable OWNER to postgres;
ERROR:  must be owner of relation mytable
```

I would like to note that the postgres user is able to fully manipulate tables that were not created with hibernate, and hibernate is able to fully manipulate the data, just not the other users I created.

Comment: You need to log in as the user that created those tables.

Answer (score 6):

So the final solution was painfully simple.  Simply:

GRANT user_you_authed_in_java TO user_you_want_to_use;